# How to permanent redirect an HTTP to HTTPS SSL url?

Tags: apache, ssl, apache2

How can I redirect any incoming HTTP requests to my local HTTPS configuration in  `apache2` on `ubuntu`?

The following does not work, because `localhost` is not replaced with the internal server ip.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        Redirect / https://localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
       ProxyPass ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Is that possible without having to explicit hardcode my local server IP into the `Redirect`?

Answer (score -2):

This should do:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
...
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]

</VirtualHost>
```

Once you are sure it works OK, change `302` to `301`

Comment: Certainly no! `mod_rewrite should be considered a last resort, when other alternatives are found wanting.` https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/avoid.html

Comment: Interesting. So you **do** have an alternative?

Comment: Well the `Redirect / 192.168.123.456` above works, with the caveat of having to hardcode the IP. But that's probably better than adding a mod_rewrite only for this single requirement... So maybe the answer is: it's not possible, except when using mod_rewrite as you suggested?

Comment: OK then, I figured that it is not that you don't want to hardcode address, but that you need a wildcard solution (where IPaddress/hostname changes, or there are multiple HTTPS virtualhosts). Anyway, while mod_rewrite should not be used easily, it is still a feature that has its use cases, and I don't think it should **never** be used.

Comment: Yes it would be great not having to set the redirect IP explicit, but instead having some kind of wildcard/dynamic host resolution. But if mod_rewrite is the only chance here I'd better hardcode.